# How to import ical .ics file in R

Tags: r, dplyr, icalendar, tidyverse

I would like to import a [.ics file](https://www.kicksonfire.com/releases/?ical=1&tribe_display=list) into R, however, when I try to do so like...

```
sneak_cal <- read.delim("iCal-TribeEvents.ics", sep = ":", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE, na.strings = "")
```

...I end up splitting the character strings of website (belonging to the `X-ORIGINAL-URL` or the `UID` field) too, which is undesirable

ie `https` and `//www.kicksonfire.com`

The ultimate goal is to get the data into a tidy format where each row represents a single `VEVENT`, which I think would be represented by a unique `UID`, without any loss of information (such as the URL)

Is there another approach that is recommended, such as pre-defining the fields that are expected as the key and matching the value or empty space to that key? Since the `.ics` file has the same expected fields each time, it seems like it might make sense to use those fields as a template to read in the data, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's an example

```
x <- readLines("https://www.kicksonfire.com/releases/?ical=1&tribe_display=list", warn = FALSE)
stopifnot(!any(grepl("^\\s+", x))) # disregarding value fields that have linefeeds for the sake of simplicity 
keyval <- do.call(rbind, regmatches(x, regexpr(":", x, fixed = TRUE), invert = TRUE))
keyval <- keyval[which.max(keyval[,1]=="BEGIN" & keyval[,2]=="VEVENT"):tail(which(keyval[,1]=="END" & keyval[,2]=="VEVENT"), 1),]
keyval <- cbind.data.frame(keyval, id=cumsum(keyval[,1]=="BEGIN" & keyval[,2]=="VEVENT"))
df <- reshape(keyval, timevar="1", idvar="id", direction = "wide")
head(df[,c(3,4,9)])
#    2.DTSTART;VALUE=DATE 2.DTEND;VALUE=DATE                              2.SUMMARY
# 1              20170422           20170423         Air Jordan 11 Low GS Blue Moon
# 14             20170422           20170423     Air Jordan 5 Premium Pure Platinum
# 27             20170427           20170428              Nike Air VaporMax Asphalt
# 40             20170427           20170428                 Nike Air VaporMax Oreo
# 53             20170427           20170428  Nike WMNS Air VaporMax White Ice Blue
# 66             20170427           20170428 wings+horns x adidas NMD R2 Light Grey
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler and more robust option available now is the `calendar` package on CRAN (documentation [here](https://atfutures.github.io/calendar/)). Importing from an ICS file to a data frame takes one line of code, and creating new events then exporting to a new ICS file is also straightforward.

Comment: calendar::ic_read("file.ics") used to work for me (last tested successfully: December 2021).
In September 2023, it fails for me (as long as there is more than one event) with this error:
Error in if (!is.na(x) & !x == "NA" & !grepl("^\\d{8}T\\d{6}Z?$", x)) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
I failed to find a bug report page for this package.
Solution by lukeA works for me.