# Export calendar from tabular data in R to ical

Tags: r, calendar, tidyverse, icalendar

I want to create calendars from tabular and computed data in R. This works well using package **toastui**, especially as it can be embedded in web pages generated with RMarkdown or Quarto. Now, I would also like to export it in `ics`/`ical` format. Is there a common way or another package in **R** to get something like this?

```r
library("toastui")
library("tibble")
library("lubridate")

## table of events
events <- tribble(
  ~title, ~start, ~end, ~category,
  "Guest talk",   "2023-03-07 15:00", "2023-03-07 17:00", "time",
  "Field Course", "2023-03-01 00:00", "2023-03-03 00:00", "allday",
  "Holidays",     "2023-03-27 00:00", "2023-03-31 00:00", "allday") |>
mutate(start = as.POSIXct(start), end=as.POSIXct(end))

## computational dates
regular <- tibble(
  title = "Weekly meeting",
  start = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-10 10:00 "), 
              as.POSIXct("2023-04-01 10:00 "), by= "1 week"),
  end   = seq(as.POSIXct("2023-03-10 12:00 "), 
              as.POSIXct("2023-04-01 12:00 "), by= "1 week "),
  category = "time"
)
  

## create toastui calendar
bind_rows(events, regular) |> 
calendar(useDetailPopup = TRUE, navigation = TRUE, defaultDate = "2023-03-16")
```

[image: example calendar]

Comment: The closest I've found is [`ical`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ical/index.html) ([git repo](https://github.com/petermeissner/ical)) but that's for parsing files, not exporting to them. The last commit was almost 3y ago, so it's unlikely under much work, but perhaps the low-activity is due to "working smoothly". You might reach out to the authors to consider the other direction.

Comment: Good point ... I have found this already ;-) but I prefer to create the raw data in tabular and not in ical format. In the past, I used colored schedules with `knitr::kable`, and a "real" calendar with **toastui** is even better, except that both have no exchange format.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading in the ical docs, I eventually used parts of a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281369/3677576) that showed how to export a single event. With this background, essential information of the calendar data frame can be exported with:

```r
#library("uuid")

format_event <- function(start, end, summary, tz = "GMT") {
  template <-"BEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:%s\nDTSTAMP:%s\nDTSTART:%s\nDTEND:%s\nSUMMARY:%s\nEND:VEVENT"
  sprintf(template, uuid::UUIDgenerate(),
    format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ", tz = tz),
    format(start, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ", tz = tz),
    format(end, "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ", tz = tz),
    summary)
}

export_calendar <- function(df, file, tz = "GMT") {
  header <- "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nPRODID:-//MyMeetings/ical //EN\nVERSION:2.0\nCALSCALE:GREGORIAN"
  footer <- "END:VCALENDAR"
  f <- file(file)
  open(f, "w")
  writeLines(header, con = f)
  invisible(lapply(1:nrow(df), \(i) {
    ic_char <- format_event(start = df$start[i], end = df$end[i],
                               summary = df$title[i], tz = tz)
    writeLines(ic_char, con = f)
  }))
  writeLines(footer, con = f)
  close(f)
}

### MAIN ###
export_calendar(df, file = "mycal.ics", tz = "CET")
```

This works for now and the [iCalendar Validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html) showed no errors, but generalized and improved versions are still welcome.